# How does Biff come back to the original time line?

Tags: back-to-the-future, back-to-the-future-ii

If Biff takes the time machine and goes back in time to deliver the Almanac to young Biff, how does old Biff return to his original time line if in the future he altered he became rich? Wouldn't he end up in the rich Biff future? Chronologically... he comes back from the past to his original time after altering the future.

Comment: I'd imagine this is because the timeline only changes gradually rather than all at once - notice how the picture Marty has of his family in the first movie only slowly fades, instead of disappearing right away as soon as he changes things. If old Biff returned whilst this gradual change was still going on immediately after he dropped off the almanac, that might explain how he ended up in the original timeline.

Comment: He didn't, see here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81773/4698.

Comment: Duplicate of [In Back to the Future Part II, why is old Biff in a lot of pain?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81773/in-back-to-the-future-part-ii-why-is-old-biff-in-a-lot-of-pain)

Comment: The answer in that duplicate covers almost everything, but I'll add here that changes to the timeline in the BTTF series don't seem to happen instantly. In the first movie, as Marty drifts further from the "I exist" path, he doesn't disappear suddenly, but gradually. So while Biff's changes meant he erased himself from existence, it consistent with the rules of the movies that he would have a buffer period where he was still around.

Comment: @Showsni Sorry, somehow I missed your comment where you basically said exactly what I did. So...yeah, what they said :)